# How to properly use TableCellRenderer to color matching cells

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm working on a program that reads data from file and puts it in the jTable.
Based on data i calculate BMI.
[image: A]

And know I'm trying to implements TableCellRenderer to color the cells in BMI column.
Color.RED - when the BMI > 25
Color.Yellow - when the BMI < 18

This is my **Renderer** which is an Frame's inner class:

```
public class BMIRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

        public BMIRenderer() {
            super.setOpaque(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {

            Person p = (Person) value;

            if (p.getBMI() < 18) {
                super.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            } else if (p.getBMI() > 25) {
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            }

            return this;
        }
    }
```

Adding renderer to jTable:

```
mainTable.setDefaultRenderer(Person.class, new BMIRenderer());
```

Aaand nothing is happening, I wass trying different methods with extending DefaultTableCellRenderer but as you can guess output was the same. I think I am missing something in the syntax with this code.

Here is the **Frame**'s code:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame {

    MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel();
    JTable mainTable = new JTable();
    JPanel jPanel;
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainTable);

    public Frame() throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
        this.setSize(new Dimension(500, 150));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        mainTable.setDefaultRenderer(Person.class, new BMIRenderer());

        mainTable.setModel(tableModel);
        scrollPane.setVisible(true);

        jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        jPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // this.pack();
        this.add(jPanel);

    public class BMIRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

        public BMIRenderer() {
            super.setOpaque(true);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {

            Person p = (Person) value;

            if (p.getBMI() < 15) {
                super.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            } else if (p.getBMI() > 25) {
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            }

            return this;
        }
    }


    }
```

**MyTableModel** class code:

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    ArrayList<Person> dataList;

    String imie, nazwisko;  //name, surname
    Color kolor;
    Integer wzrostCm, wagaKg; //weight, height
    Calendar cal;
    Person p;

    int BMI;
    int r, g, b;

    public MyTableModel() throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
        dataList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\ziole\\EclipseWorkspace\\GUI_z07P_DOING\\src\\tabelka.txt"));

        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

        System.out.println("Wczytany plik:");
        while (read.hasNext()) {
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String newLine = read.nextLine();
            String[] elements = newLine.split(" ");

            System.out.println(newLine);

            imie = elements[0];
            nazwisko = elements[1];

            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(elements[2]);
            cal.setTime(date);

            String[] RGB = elements[3].split(",");
            r = Integer.parseInt(RGB[0]);
            g = Integer.parseInt(RGB[1]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(RGB[2]);
            kolor = new Color(r, g, b);

            wzrostCm = new Integer(elements[4]);
            wagaKg = new Integer(elements[5]);

            BMI = bmi(wagaKg, wzrostCm);

            dataList.add(new Person(imie, nazwisko, kolor, wzrostCm, wagaKg, cal, BMI));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        p = dataList.get(rowIndex);

        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return p.imie;
        case 1:
            return p.nazwisko;
        case 2:
            return data(cal, p);
        case 3:
            return p.kolor.getRGB();
        case 4:
            return p.wzrostCm;
        case 5:
            return p.wagaKg;
        case 6:
            return p.BMI;

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return "Imie";
        case 1:
            return "Nazwisko";
        case 2:
            return "data";
        case 3:
            return "Kolor";
        case 4:
            return "Wzrost[cm]";
        case 5:
            return "Waga[kg]";
        case 6:
            return "BMI";
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String data(Calendar cal, Person p) {
        // po Galicyjsku
        switch (p.cal.get(cal.MONTH)) {
        case 0:
            return "xaneiro";
        case 1:
            return "febreiro";
        case 2:
            return "marzo";
        case 3:
            return "abril";
        case 4:
            return "maio";
        case 5:
            return "xuño";
        case 6:
            return "xullo";
        case 7:
            return "agosto";
        case 8:
            return "setembro";
        case 9:
            return "outubro";
        case 10:
            return "novembro";
        case 11:
            return "decembro";

        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;

    }

    public int bmi(Integer waga, Integer wzrostCm) {

        double wzrostKwadrat = (int) Math.pow(wzrostCm, 2);
        double wynik = Math.round(((waga / wzrostKwadrat) * 10000));
        return (int) wynik;

    }


}
```

And **Person** class:

```
public class Person {

    String imie, nazwisko;
    Color kolor;
    int r, g, b;
    Integer wzrostCm, wagaKg;
    Calendar cal;
    int BMI;

    public Person(String imie, String nazwisko, Color kolor, Integer wzrostCm, Integer wagaKg, Calendar cal, int BMI) {
        this.imie = imie;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this.kolor = kolor;
        this.wzrostCm = wzrostCm;
        this.wagaKg = wagaKg;
        this.cal = cal;
        this.BMI = BMI;
    }
*here are simple getters and setters*
}
```

File from which I read:

```
Jan Kowalski 1980-2-7 255,0,153 182 99
Michał Nowak 1988-8-13 0,0,153 177 73
Zofia Michalska 1971-6-12 255,0,51 162 53
Łukasz Gwózdz 1975-3-23 0,0,255 178 47
Tomasz Wójcik 1965-1-7 102,0,0 180 50
Beata Szczesniak 2000-8-28 51,102,0 160 70
Anna Pekala 1979-2-17 0,204,255 164 54
Robert Tarski 1971-11-2 255,102,0 176 70
```

In Main I am just creating **Frame's** Object.

Comment: Can you turn this into an [SSCE](http://sscce.org) please?

Comment: why are you using `JPanel` and not `JLabel`? Can you try `public class BMIRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {` instead? You could also just extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer` or not? Might be simpler?

Comment: Ok, I switched it to jLabel where should i see the difference?

Comment: This was just a suggestion. I've to run your code first to see what's happening

Comment: would be good if you also share the `Person` class with us

Comment: you attached the BMIRenderer to each column of type `Person` - but, in fact none of your columns is of type `Person` ...

Comment: so it should be an Object type? 
it crashes when i'm changing it :/
/or Color.class

Comment: oh, not Color.class definitely xd , I changed the code to this from the comment below but still something is not quite right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your renderer to extend DefaultTableCellRenderer, override the getTableCellRendererComponent() method:

```
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class BMIRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Person person = null;
        String bmiValue = "";
        if(value instanceof Person) {
            person = (Person)value;
            bmiValue = Integer.toString(person.getBMI());
        }

        //Pass just the bmiValue to the super method so the integer's toString() value is displayed
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, bmiValue, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if(person != null) {
            if (person.getBMI() < 18) {
                super.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            } 
            else if (person.getBMI() > 25) {
                setBackground(Color.RED);
            }
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, modify your table model so that it returns the entire Person object for column 6, instead of the int value of the BMI field:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    Person person = dataList.get(rowIndex);

    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return person.imie;
        case 1:
            return person.nazwisko;
        case 2:
            return data(cal, person);
        case 3:
            return person.kolor.getRGB();
        case 4:
            return person.wzrostCm;
        case 5:
            return person.wagaKg;
        case 6:
            //Return the entire Person object so that the column class matches to our custom cell renderer
            return person;

    }

    return null;
}
```

In your MyTableModel class, override the getColumnClass() method as follows:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return String.class;
        case 1:
            return String.class;
        case 2:
            return String.class;
        case 3:
            return Integer.class;
        case 4:
            return Integer.class;
        case 5:
            return Integer.class;
        case 6:
            return Person.class;

    }
    return Object.class;
}
```

Comment: in which way should i return it? Simple "return p" is giving me the hashcode of person

Comment: Ok i change the mainTable.setDefaultRenderer(Person.class, new BMIRenderer()); to Object.class and know everything (i mean whole jTable) is .red and .yellow :/

Comment: @Mikosz if you got the hashcode of person, it is because your Person class does not override toString() and your custom renderer was not used to render the value.  The way I coded the renderer, it should only be used for the BMI column #6.

Comment: oh, so should I override it?
like: 
@Override
 public String toString() {
  return BMI;
 }

Comment: @Mikosz in your JFrame constructor, try calling mainTable.setDefaultRenderer() after you call mainTable.setModel() because I have a feeling that setting the model after the renderer is causing the renderer to be replaced with a default renderer instead of the one you created.

Comment: ok, I've changed that and overrided toString(), it gives me right values of BMI by returning person but there is no colors :/ What arguments should be placed in .setDefaultrenderer( ? , new BMIRenderer )?

Comment: I updated my answer to override getColumnClass() in your MyTableModel class.  In your call to setDefaultRenderer() pass Person.class as the first parameter so your custom renderer is used for column 6, BMI.

Comment: Oh man, You are the best.
I understand that my program needs this getColumnClass() method to recognize class-types so it can work on int? Or something like that

Comment: Would you have time to help me with another problem? Maybe you have noticed this weird "Kolor" column.. i have to manage it to change the whole cell color that is saved in every cell. Should i use another Renderer or can I manage it in BMIRenderer?